# How to add data to Firebase Child from different view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add data to the child I created during signup but I can't seem to reference it from the other view controller. I'm using swift btw.

Comment: How do you try to get the reference? How do try to add the child. What is the original reference? Can you see the data added online? How does it look?

Comment: Give your Json tree , be more clear...